# Can't understand how passing function to update state hook works

Tags: javascript, reactjs, asynchronous

In the following code:

```
// create state count
const [count,setCount] = useState(0)

//update state 
setCount(count-1)
setCount(count-1)
```

The value of count decreases by one only, because setCount() is an asynchronous function. I understand this. But why does the following code work fine, i.e count is decreased by two when a function is passed instead of a statement?

```
setCount(prevCount => prevCount-1)
setCount(prevCOunt => prevCount-1)
```

Why does the same behaviour as in the first case not appear here? I have limited experience with async functions and am new to react. Thanks for reading!

Comment: https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#state-updates-may-be-asynchronous

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> The value of count decreases by one only, because setCount() is an
> asynchronous function

No. It is decreased by 1 even with two `setCount` calls because you pass `count - 1` to both function calls. In both calls, you are passing the *same* value.

Reason why `count` is not updated *after* the first `setCount` call is because state is constant within a particular render of a component. Component can't see the updated state until it re-renders.

If the value of `count` is 5, then the following

```
setCount(count-1)
setCount(count-1)
```

is like

```
setCount(5 - 1)
setCount(5 - 1)
```

> Why does the same behaviour as in the first case not appear here?

That's because when you pass a function to `setCount`, `prevCount` is the most recent value of `count`. In this case, you are *not* subtracting 1 from the *same* value of `count`.

If the value of `count` is 5, then the following

```
setCount(prevCount => prevCount-1)
setCount(prevCount => prevCount-1)
```

is like

```
setCount(5 => 5 - 1)
setCount(4 => 4 - 1)
```